# XTend null safe throws NullPointerException

Tags: nullpointerexception, xtend

I am porting my template code to XTend. At some point I have this type of condition handling in a test case:

```
@Test
def xtendIfTest() {
    val obj = new FD
    if (true && obj?.property?.isNotNull) {
        return
    }
    fail("Not passed")
}

def boolean isNotNull(Object o) {
    return o != null
}
class FD {
 @Accessors
 String property
}
```

This works as expected as the property is null and the test will fail with "Not passed" message. But a simple change in the return type of isNotNull method to Boolean (wrapper):

```
def Boolean isNotNull(Object o) {
    return o != null
}
```

fails with a NullPointerException. Examining the generated java code for this I can see that XTend is using an intermediate Boolean object expression and that is the cause of NPE. Am I missing the point of the XTend null safe operator (?.) or I can't use a method like this after the operator?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operator behaves properly. The exception is thrown because of the usage of a Boolean in an if-expression, which requires auto-unboxing.

If you try the following:

```
@Test
def xtendIfTest() {
    val Boolean obj = null
    if (obj) {
        return
    }
    fail("Not passed")
}
```

You will also run into a NullPointerException.

This is consistent with the Java Language Specification (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.8) - when auto-unboxing is required this can yield a NullPointerException:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    Boolean value = null;
    if (value) { // warning: Null pointer access: This expression of type Boolean is null but requires auto-unboxing
        // dead code
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer:** Change the second null-safe call to a regular call.

I.e. change

```
obj?.property?.isNotNull
```

to this:

```
obj?.property.isNotNull
```

**Long answer:**

The [docs](http://www.eclipse.org/xtend/documentation/203_xtend_expressions.html#null-safe-feature-calls) describe the null-safe operator thusly:

> In many situations it is ok for an expression to return null if a
>   receiver was null

That means the second call in your example, `property?.` won't even call `isNotNull` if the left side of the call was `null`. Instead, it will return `null`. So the conditional "effectively" evaluates to:

```
if (true && null) {  // causes NPE when java tries to unbox the Boolean
```

(By the way - the `true` is superfluous in this context, but I'm keeping it just in case you had another condition to check - I'm assuming you're just simplifying it to `true` for this example.)

If you make the change I'm suggesting, `obj?.property` will be evaluated, then the result will be passed to `isNotNull`, evaluating to this:

```
if (true && isNotNull(null)) {
```

which returns the proper `Boolean` object that will be auto-unboxed as expected.

**A Word of Caution**

In your first form of `isNotNull`, i.e. the one returning primitive `boolean`, you should actually get a warning like "Null-safe call of primitive-valued feature isNotNull, default value false will be used".

This is because you're stretching the intent of the null-safe call, which is to return `null` without invoking the right side method if the left side of the operator was `null`. But if your `isNotNull` returns a primitive `boolean`, the whole expression obviously can't evaluate to `null`, so Xtend uses a default instead, which is `false` for booleans.

To emphasize the problem in a different way - it evaluates to `false` *without* calling `isNotNull` - that means even if you used a method `isNull` after the operator, it would *still* return `false`!

The docs also mention this behavior (albeit in general terms):

> For primitive types the default value is returned (e.g. 0 for int).
>   This may not be what you want in some cases, so a warning will be
>   raised by default

So I recommend always using a non-primitive return value on the right-hand side of a null-safe call. But if you're going to convert the `isNotNull` to a regular call as I suggested, this rule doesn't apply, and either return type is fine.